# batch file exits before input criteria is satisfied

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, recursion, directory, explorer

I've created a batch file to right click in explorer and ask the user for a folder name. If the folder already exists, I want to keep asking the user until one that does not exist is entered. The file exits after two runs through if the folder already exists and I can't figure out why this happens. It looks to me like it should continually call main until it gets a folder name that doesn't exist. See code below

```
set verbose=NO
@echo off

set mydir = %cd%
cd %mydir%
cls

call:main
echo returned from main
pause
goto:eof

:main
set /p job=Enter Job Name:
echo %job%
call:check
echo returned from check
if choice==1 call:main
echo returned from main
pause
if choice==2 call:createDirectory

:check
if exist %job% (echo Folder already exists set choice=1) else (set choice=2)
echo %choice%



:createDirectory
md "%job%"

md "%job%"\1.Development
md "%job%"\1.Development\1.Budgets
md "%job%"\1.Development\2.Manufacturers

md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"
md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"\1.Plans
md "%job%"\"2.Plans and Specs"\2.Specs

md "%job%"\3.Pricing
md "%job%"\3.Pricing\1.Quotes
md "%job%"\3.Pricing\2.Worksheets

md "%job%"\4.Sumbittals
md "%job%"\4.Sumbittals\"1.Submittal Reviews"

md "%job%"\5.Orders
md "%job%"\5.Orders\"1.Order Summaries"
md "%job%"\5.Orders\"2.Confirmation Pages"

md "%job%"\6.Closeout
md "%job%"\6.Closeout\"1.O&M Manuals"
md "%job%"\6.Closeout\2.Warranty
```

Comment: In `:check`, add a "&" in between 2 commands, `echo Folder already exists & set choice=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `check` subroutine doesn't return to the caller but proceeds to the end of the batch file, add `exit /b` after `echo %choice%`
2. In the `main` subroutine: add `goto main` before the next label to make it loop
3. You're calling `:main` recursively, use `goto main` without colon: `if choice==1 goto main` but actually you don't need this line due to #2 above
4. Use `&` to separate commands on one line: `(echo Folder already exists & set choice=1)`
5. Use `%variable%` to get its value: `if %choice%==2 call :createDirectory`

Here's the changed code between `:main` and `:createDirectory`:

```
:main
set /p job=Enter Job Name:
call:check
if %choice%==2 call :createDirectory
goto main

:check
if exist %job% (echo Folder already exists & set choice=1) else (set choice=2)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm! Only thing you forgot to mention is adding exit at the end of the file to terminate. How do I add a 3 second wait before it exits? Add a -w 3000 before call :createDirectory?

Comment: 1. You haven't explicitly stated that the batch should exit in case of success. 2. `timeout 3` on a separate line before the final `exit`.